# Hexagonal packaging of spheres inside the cylinder

Tags: matlab, geometry, packing

I have some cylinder of radius `R` and spheres of radius `r`. I try to find an algorithm on how to pack these spheres inside the cylinder hexagonally. I guess that it should be solved a thousand times, but it seems i don't know the right question to Google.

**Could You help me to find a solution (link)?**

P.S. I would be extremely happy if it is done for Matlab.

Comment: is this problem 3D? if so, the height of the cylinder should be included and the solution may not be as simple as you might think. If not, please use 2D names. Do you want to know the maximum numbers, or are you after a (non-unique!) set of coordinates for the spheres?

Comment: You could just scavenge the source code of this https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/smaller-circles-in-larger-circle-d_1849.html if all you want is 2D (I don't know if the solution is optimal).

Comment: I need the close packing in 3D. As I understand the height of the cylinder does not matter, as all odd/even layers would be equal, just different height.

Comment: If I use a well-known search engine and search on the phrase *Hexagonal packaging of spheres inside the cylinder* I get a good few useful hits right on the first page of results.

Comment: It does matter! For example, if only 2 layers could possibly fit, 2 odd layers will be more efficient than a odd/even combination. But you are right that the solution is quasi-periodic.